# Site to Site VPN with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vpn

First of I'm very sorry but this questions is not so so specific.

All I am looking for is a tutorial or a resource for creating a site-to-site VPN.
Actually, I not even sure if that is what I should call it.
I live in China and I want to access youtube and stuff.
And I don't want to buy a proxy service so I'm trying to make my own VPN or proxy with Ruby on Rails.

So again, my question is where is a resource for creating site-to-site VPN with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be easier to use software designed for creating VPNs instead of writing your own. OpenVPN (http://openvpn.net/) immediately springs to mind

Answer (score 0):

sorry about the thread russurection, but if he wants to make money I would choose openswan.  OpenVPN went commercial for more than 2 users.  You could set up the openswan VPN and do some web redirection inside of rails.  That's one approach.